# Sencha Javascript Insert to Array First Index

Tags: javascript, extjs

I requesting products from my web service. And i want insert to object array's first index the new item.

my lounch function :

```
NewMobile.globals = {
    mesaj: 'selam',
    action: '',
    server: '192.168.50.70',
    branchCode: '0',
    activeTable: '',
    activeFolio: '0',
    activeTableGroup: '',
    activeMustGroup: -1,
    activePid: 0,
    activeMustGroupString: 0,
    activeMustDesc: '',
    activeMustArray: [],
    activeCampProduct: '',
    products: undefined,
    rePrint: '',
    activePax: 1,
    uuid: 'tanimsiz',
    activeSkin: 'Krem',
    version:undefined,
    minVersion:132
};
```

Its my request.

```
NewMobile.globals.products = Ext.create('NewMobile.store.PorductStore');
NewMobile.globals.products.setProxy({url: "http://" + NewMobile.globals.server + ':1002/zulu/newmobile/data.aspx?act=getAllProducts'});
NewMobile.globals.products.getProxy();
NewMobile.globals.products.load(function(a, records, c, d, e){
    if (c !== true)
    {

        Ext.Viewport.setMasked(false);
        Ext.Msg.alert('uyarı', NewMobile.message.connectionError, Ext.emptyFn);

        return;
    }
    else
    {
    if(NewMobile.globals.version!==undefined)
    {

           if(NewMobile.globals.version.MinorRevision>=NewMobile.globals.minVersion)
        {
            var PopulerProducts=Ext.create('NewMobile.model.Products',
                              { id:-65000,
                    name:"SIK KULLANILANLAR",
                    groupId:200000,
                    color:"#FFC673",
                    type:1,
                    order:-1,
                    mustModGroups:0,
                    mustModGrpCount:0
        }
                             );

    NewMobile.globals.products.unshift(PopulerProducts);


        }

    }
    }

});
```

Product Model :

```
Ext.define('NewMobile.model.Products', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    requires: [
        'Ext.data.Field'
    ],

    config: {
        fields: [
            {
                name: 'id',
                type: 'int'
            },
            {
                name: 'name',
                type: 'string'
            },
            {
                name: 'groupId',
                type: 'int'
            },
            {
                name: 'price',
                type: 'float'
            },
            {
                name: 'color'
            },
            {
                name: 'type',
                type: 'int'
            },
            {
                name: 'mustModGrpCount'
            },
            {
                name: 'mustModGroups'
            },
            {
                name: 'order',
                type: 'int'
            },
            {
                name: 'campCount',
                type: 'int'
            },
            {
                name: 'stockCode'
            },
            {
                name: 'populer',
                type: 'boolean'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Chrome console giving this error.

Object [object Object] has no method 'unshift'

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your `NewMobile.store.PorductStore` is extending `Ext.store.Store`. To add items to a store you can either use the `add` or `insert` method.

`add` will add the items to the end of the store so what you want to use is `insert` and specify the index to be 0. Something like this:

```
myStore.insert(0, newRecord)
```

To keep the sorting use `addSorted`. Inserts the passed Record into the Store at the index where it should go based on the current sort information.

```
myStore.addSorted(newRecord)
```

You can read more about how to use stores in Ext.js here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store

Comment: Hi carcel thanks for answer.

 NewMobile.globals.products is my object array its not store. im sorting this array for name ascending. when i tried your code before its work fine but my sort deleted.

Comment: Can you add the definition of the NewMobile.store.PorductStore to the question? Using Store is a misleading name for an regular array.

Comment: added lounch function

Comment: actually my problem is "sorter". i tried "insert" method and worked. but automaticly added sorter. before the insert array values geting "alphabetical", after the insert adding sorter and sorting by "order". how can i fix this ?

Comment: If you want to keep the sorting and add the record in the right place, try using the "addSorted" method.